# Firebase Admin Send Multicast not getting called or working

Tags: python, django, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm working on django project in which i need to send notifications to the users using firebase admin sdk. but when ever i tried to send notification i see no logs for messaging.send_multicast(message). can anyone help me on this?

```
message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
 data={
 'data': str(self.data)
 },
 tokens=registration_tokens,
)
print('message', message)
response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
print('response', response.success_count, response.failure_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above to send a multicast data message is correct and should work. Do you get any errors?

Also have you made sure to initialise the Firebase admin SDK with correct credentials:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging

cred = credentials.Certificate(<credentials_path>)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

If you want to send a notification that's visible on the user's phone, should use the `notification` attribute, like so:

```
message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title="Notification Title",
        body="Notification Text",
    ),
    tokens=registration_tokens
)

response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
print('response', response.success_count, response.failure_count)
```